# Forms authentication over http in WCF - how do I know which user is calling me

Tags: wcf, authentication, cookies, forms-authentication

I'm working on a client-server application using WCF. The first client will be a desktop app (WPF) but I plan to add Xamarin (Android and iOS) and web client. I want this to be an internet service, and to potentially support a large number of clients, so I'm using http, a stateless service to conserve server resources.

I am having difficulties implementing authentication logic.
I found this great example that implements forms authentication:

http://www.dotnetspeak.com/wcf/securing-wcf-with-forms-authentication/

It allows me to handle authentication how I want - compare username and password against the database, create an authentication cookie and return it. Subsequent calls using this cookie will be authenticated automatically.

But the problem is, I don't know which user called the service. If GetMyData() is called by user1, I want to make sure he only gets his own data. I obviously don't want to have the client send their ID separately with each request, because that can be easily tampered with - just switch "user1" for "user2" and hey presto, you're getting someone else's data.
I can get to the authentication cookie inside the service method by calling

```
WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Cookie]
```

(I can also see there's one other header called "Host")

The cookie is generated from a FormsAuthenticationTicket, which contains the username and password, but it's encrypted. I'm not sure whether it's possible for me to decrypt the cookie in my code, but I'm pretty sure it wouldn't be the correct approach. My method was called AFTER the underlying system authenticated the caller, so presumably the cookie was decrypted and the ticket was found to be valid. So why can't I get to the data?

Sadly, every article I've found only deals with authenticating the user, but nobody seems to care about which user is using the service afterwards, as long as he's authorized.

I suppose I could store the cookies server-side, along with mapping to the specific user, and find the user that way. But I want the service to be as stateless as possible for performance reasons. Also, this would involve doing  fulltext matching on a 300 character long string - for every single request! Yikes!

It seems to me that what I need is a very common use case, so there must be a proper way to do it. I just can't seem to find it. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Forms authentication setup correctly then you can get the logged-in username via Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name and send it to your service method for data access validation. Get the user id from username and validate ownership.

Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name decrypts the cookie ticket and returns the logged-in username.

Comment: I tried looking at the value in the Watch window while inside the service method. There was no 'Thread' available:
error CS0103: The name 'Thread' does not exist in the current context
You wrote "send it to your service method". I don't understand. Send it from where?

Comment: I usually expose a web api project and not WCF to the internet. In asp.net applications, you have access to the logged-in identity name by User.Identity.Name or by Thread...Name. In your case, where WCF is exposed, there must be a way to have access to these values. Note: i hate exposing WCF service to the internet directly, instead it is better to expose asp.net web api / mvc to the internet and let it communicate with your WCF but this is out of the scope of your request i assume.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Based on your original answer I did some more searching and found out I should have access to ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name. However my ServiceSecurityContext.Current is null, which means I need to configure a http binding properly. However you've made me realize I'm facing a bigger question regarding the architecture of my service, and that I just know too little about the subject to proceed. Rather than continue mucking about blindly, I'll need to do some more studying.

Comment: Well you didn't exactly solve my problem, but alright.

Comment: Thanks @Shaggydog. I can help you achieve what you are looking for if needed.